# Send data with ajax without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi guys I'm trying to send data via POST Request without refreshing the page with AJAX, but my code don't work, and I cand understand why:
HTML

```
<input type="button" class="button1"  onclick="send(<?=$i?>);/>
```

JS:

```
function send(Input){
    var Data=document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[Input];
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{name:Data},
        cache:"false",
    });
}
```

I'm sending data to the same page so I didn't specified the URL.
PHP:

```
<?php
   $Data=$_POST['name'];
   echo "$Data";
?>
```

I didn't get no echo from php, but from ajax if i write for example `document.write(Data);`I get the input that i expect.

Comment: Have you tried $_POST['name'] ? Because you're sending data from ajax request as name so you can catch like this.

Comment: what is purpose of  var data=document.getElementsByClassName('button1')[Input]; If you have get value of input

Comment: `Data` should be `Data.value`.

Answer (score 0):

how can you get `$_POST['Input']` if you passed `$_POST['name']`?
in you php file you must to do `$data = $_POST['name'];`

Comment: I have tryied it now but still don't work, but i get thies erroe on console from java:TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Comment: @SirCascada There's no `stepUp` in the code you posted, that's an unrelated problem.

Comment: I know infact i don't have any stepUp, i can't understand what is happening.